# PHP eBay GetOrders API (Unable To fetch Any Data)

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am Trying to fetch ebay orders by using `getOrders API`, when i execute ebay PHP SDK it print:

"Sorry No entries found in the Time period requested. Change CreateTimeFrom/CreateTimeTo and Try again"

Please Help me...

Official ebay PHP SDK code :

```
<?php
/*  © 2013 eBay Inc., All Rights Reserved */ 
/* Licensed under CDDL 1.0 -  http://opensource.org/licenses/cddl1.php */
?>
<?php require_once('get-common/keys.php') ; //include keys file for auth token and other credentials ?>
<?php require_once('get-common/eBaySession.php') ; //include session file for curl operations ?>
<?php
//SiteID must also be set in the Request's XML
//SiteID = 0  (US) - UK = 3, Canada = 2, Australia = 15, ....
//SiteID Indicates the eBay site to associate the call with
$siteID = 0;
//the call being made:
$verb = 'GetOrders';

//Time with respect to GMT
//by default retreive orders in last 30 minutes
$CreateTimeFrom = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",time()-(2*40*24*60*60)); //current time minus 80 Days

//echo "</br>";
$CreateTimeTo = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");


//If you want to hard code From and To timings, Follow the below format in "GMT".
//$CreateTimeFrom = YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS; //GMT
//$CreateTimeTo = YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS; //GMT


///Build the request Xml string
$requestXmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
$requestXmlBody .= '<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
$requestXmlBody .= '<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>';
$requestXmlBody .= "<CreateTimeFrom>".$CreateTimeFrom."</CreateTimeFrom><CreateTimeTo>".$CreateTimeTo."</CreateTimeTo>";
$requestXmlBody .= '<OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole><OrderStatus>All</OrderStatus>';
$requestXmlBody .= "<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>$userToken</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>";
$requestXmlBody.="<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>";
$requestXmlBody .= '</GetOrdersRequest>';

//Create a new eBay session with all details pulled in from included keys.php
$session = new eBaySession($userToken, $devID, $appID, $certID, $serverUrl, $compatabilityLevel, $siteID, $verb);

//send the request and get response
$responseXml = $session->sendHttpRequest($requestXmlBody);
if (stristr($responseXml, 'HTTP 404') || $responseXml == '')
    die('<P>Error sending request');

//echo "<pre>";
//var_dump($responseXml);

//die;


//Xml string is parsed and creates a DOM Document object
$responseDoc = new DomDocument();
$responseDoc->loadXML($responseXml);


//get any error nodes
$errors = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Errors');
$response = simplexml_import_dom($responseDoc);
$entries = $response->PaginationResult->TotalNumberOfEntries;

//if there are error nodes
if ($errors->length > 0) {
    echo '<P><B>eBay returned the following error(s):</B>';
    //display each error
    //Get error code, ShortMesaage and LongMessage
    $code = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ErrorCode');
    $shortMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ShortMessage');
    $longMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('LongMessage');

    //Display code and shortmessage
    echo '<P>', $code->item(0)->nodeValue, ' : ', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $shortMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));

    //if there is a long message (ie ErrorLevel=1), display it
    if (count($longMsg) > 0)
        echo '<BR>', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $longMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));
}else { //If there are no errors, continue
    if(isset($_GET['debug']))
    {  
       header("Content-type: text/xml");
       print_r($responseXml);
    }else
     {  //$responseXml is parsed in view.php
        include_once 'view.php';
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the ebay-sdk-php from devbay.net :

https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php

https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples

As for the date, I could be wrong, but I think it requires DateTime.  Something like

```
 CreateTimeFrom = new DateTime('02-10-2016');
 CreateTimeTo = new DateTime('02-11-2016');
```

But I think you will have an easier time with the ebay-sdk-php

edit:

Actually I've been messing around with this more lately.

The default works for me

```
$CreateTimeFrom = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",time()-1800); //current time minus 30 minutes
$CreateTimeTo = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
```

or you can hardcode your range like the following:

```
//If you want to hard code From and To timings, Follow the below format in "GMT".
//$CreateTimeFrom = YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS; //GMT
//$CreateTimeTo = YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS; //GMT
```

such as the following:

```
$CreateTimeFrom = '2017-03-20T00:00:00Z'; //GMT
$CreateTimeTo   = '2017-03-22T00:00:00Z'; //GMT
```

Alternatively, you can just simply not use `CreatedTimeTo` and `CreatedTimeFrom` and use `NumberOfDays` instead

which is basically just commenting out `CreatedTimeTo` and `CreatedTimeFrom`

```
//$requestXmlBody .= "<CreateTimeFrom>$CreateTimeFrom</CreateTimeFrom><CreateTimeTo>$CreateTimeTo</CreateTimeTo>";
```

and directly underneath it use `NumberOfDays`

```
 $requestXmlBody .= "<NumberOfDays>2</NumberOfDays>";
```